# Unable to access my application from outside kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have deployed the Kubernetes cluster in the Azure platform. My application is hosted in azure docker and i deployed the docker image into my Kubernetes cluster. After deploying the pods are running fine. But I was not able to access the application from outside (postman/talentapi). Nginx Ingress controller is installed inside the cluster but still not able to access the application and getting no response error. Our application uses 2 different ports (5000 & 7003). Port 7003 is used to connect the application inside docker and port 5000 used to connect outside docker. Here by im sharing my service.yaml file,

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: kyc-service
 namespace: kyc
spec:
 #type: ClusterIP
 selector:
   app: kyc-app
 ports:
 - name: http
   protocol: TCP
   port: 5000
   targetPort: 5000
 - name: kycapp
   protocol: TCP
   port: 7003
   targetPort: 7003
```

Comment: Can you create an ingress rule for your application service? If you didn't, you should do it.

Comment: Hi Oguzhan, Yes I already created the ingress (nginx ingress controller) yaml and deployed the same in the cluster.

Comment: Can you past your ingress rules as well? Is your ingress rules covering kyc namespace?

Comment: Hi, there is  no ingress.yaml here.

Comment: apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kyc-ingress
  namespace: kyc
  annotations:
    # add an annotation indicating the issuer to use
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: http01
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - kyctest.in-d.ai
    secretName: kyc-ingress-tls
  rules:
  - host: kyctest.in-d.ai
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kyc-service
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /
Hi Oguzhan, This is our ingress....